# Do I need to use OAuth to get a feed of latest posts from an FB group of which I am admin?

Tags: facebook, oauth

I am admin on an FB group and I want to get a feed of the latest posts for inclusion in a website. How do I do this? Excuse the simplicity of the question. However, I have done some research and I understand that I need an access_token, but do I really need to do some full oAuth stuff for a public group?

Comment: I had suggest you to go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/, try things and then ask a specific question.

Comment: [As the docs tell you](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/), for the feed connection of a group you just need “any valid access token”, so if the group is public, an app access token will do. So just create an app, and then you can use the combination app_id|app_secret as app access token. But be aware that you should only use that in server-side code, the app secret or an app access token should never be exposed in client-side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to put access token to get feed but no need to worry this access token can't share your any details.it just a token to get feed.

You can generate your access token no. here.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET

And you can get feed for your page with following url:

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Thanks

Comment: you don't need to use Oauth for this then?

Comment: sorry can you explain your question

Comment: Oauth is a 3-legged mode of authenticating with Faceboook- so you would make a request, get a token back for the session, and then use that to be logged in for a certain period of time and get access until it expires. How else do you get the token?